# What is the species of these mushrooms?

Tags: taxonomy, species-identification, mycology

The mushrooms are gilled with a light-brown cap. The stem is widened to the base.

What species is it? Is it considered edible?

They are found in mixed forest in Moscow, Russia. They grow in the ground quite separated from each other.

[image]

Comment: Looks like [Boletus edulis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boletus_edulis). If that is the case is not only edible but extremely yummy. **However, please do not trust me too much on this**, I am no mushroom expert.

Comment: @nico it cannot be boletus because it is gilled, while boletus is pored.

Comment: Please, describe where have you found them (geographic location, type of habitat). This kind of information is very useful for species identification.

Comment: @Anixx: told you not to trust me on that :P

Comment: @Marta Cz-C done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Clitocybe Nebularis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitocybe_nebularis), an edible species.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick look in my books (for the British Isles and Europe) but although I found a couple of candidates I don't feel confident in either identification.

I suggest that you have a look at [Roger Phillips' online identification guide](http://www.rogersmushrooms.com/)  - this will suggest a few identification criteria that you haven't considered in your question.

Comment: "No results found. We were unable to find a match for your search."

Comment: For the record, my two candidates were False Death Cap (immature specimens) and St. George's Mushroom (but this is a spring fruiting species). These were based on the general colour and swollen stem base only.

Comment: @Alan Boyd the cap is smooth and there is no veil at the basement. Also there is no skirt. Very far from False Death Cap.

Comment: @Alan Boyd My candidates are species of Cortinarius genus (Cortinarius glaucopus http://for-grib.ru/IMAGES/pautinnik-sizonozhkovyjj-cortinarius-glaucopus-lllo5b.jpeg Cortinarius praestans http://www.aranzadi-zientziak.org/fileadmin/images/micologia/Eskaneatuak/09_digital/cortinarius_praestans_paa_091103.jpg Cortinarius esculentus http://infofishing.ru/uploads/posts/2011-12/1322998170_pautinnik.jpg ), Tricholoma portentosum http://www.dipbot.unict.it/funghi_etna/photogallery/Tricholoma%20portentosum.jpg Clytocybe nebularis http://nepoganki.narod.ru/Photos/074_photo.jpg

Comment: http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5190/5602239343_08378ce877_m.jpg

Comment: Or Clitocybe clavipes http://mycoweb.narod.ru/fungi/Submitted/SJG2/Clitocybe_clavipes_JS20040829_med.jpg

Comment: It turned out to be young Clitocybe Nebularis, an edible and tasty mushroom.